# How can I get user-Id in parse cloud code function?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, userid

I'm calling a parse cloud code function from android app, and I need userId (objectId) to read some data about him.

The question is, how can I get the userId?

I know how to do it with params, but it's already in the request (image below).

[userId_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF13Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current logged in user id via `request.user.id`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly that I was looking for.